# Slicing an image based on peaks

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have the following peak detection that I did using hilbert transform that gets the envelop of a signal, then I detect the peaks out of it.

I would like to cut out those peaks from peak 1, to peak 2, and from peak 2, to peak 3, and from peak 3 to peak 4, and so on.

That's a sample image:

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tt9l.png)

and That's result of the process

[peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX0J8.png)

and that's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy import signal
from math import factorial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import scipy.signal.signaltools as sigtool
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths, find_peaks_cwt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema


# ---------------------------------------Functions---------------------------------------------------#


def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm == 0:
        return v
    return v / norm


'''
reduces the photo to a vector representing its pixel freuqeuncy at each column 
'''


def image_reduce(img):
    col_counts = cv2.reduce(img, 0, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)
    column = col_counts.flatten().tolist()
    # print("Column counts:\n\n", column)
    return column


def histogram_plot(convluted_word, peaks, fit):
    plt.plot(convluted_word)
    plt.plot(fit, 'r')
    plt.plot(peaks, fit[peaks], "x")
    plt.show()




# ---------------------------------------Main Code Flow---------------------------------------------------#
# ---------------------------an example on how to use this package----------------------------------------#

def slice_digits(image_name):
    img = cv2.imread(image_name, 0)

    column_frequency = image_reduce(cv2.bitwise_not(img))
    column_frequency = normalize(column_frequency)

    env = np.abs(sigtool.hilbert(column_frequency))

    square_sig = (env > 0.1)
    square_sig = square_sig.astype(float)
    square_sig = np.divide(square_sig, 15.0)
    square_sig = np.where((column_frequency > 0), 0.1, 0)

    peaks, _ = find_peaks(env > 0.1)
    plt.plot(env)
    plt.scatter(peaks, env[peaks],  s = 50, c = 'r')

    edges = np.nonzero(np.diff(square_sig))[0]
    plt.scatter(edges, env[edges], c = 'g')
    plt.show()
    all_slices = []
    for i in range(len(peaks) - 1):
        x0, x1 = peaks[i:i + 2]
        image_slice = img[x0:x1]
        # Now do something with the slice, e.g.
        cv2.imshow("slice",image_slice)

        all_slices.append(image_slice)

    # used for debugging
    #histogram_plot(column_frequency, peaks, square_sig)

    # segements the picture
    #listt, image_final = char_slicer(edges, img)
    plt.show()

    # display result
    #return image_final


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = r"c:\ahmed\doc.png"
    res_image = slice_digits(image)
```

What I want is something like that:

[desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q26Zq.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking to do; you talk about slicing an image, but in the "desired" image you show the peaks plot with rectangles on. Did you mean to show the rectangles on the original image?

Comment: @jmetz Yea the frequency spectrum of the image, can be sliced to get a sliced characters, out from the peaks...In other words, cut the original image based on the rectangles, to get the different letters

Comment: I can't reproduce your plots as your code is incomplete (e.g. no `image_reduce`), but you should just be able to use the `peaks` variable to slice from the image.

Comment: @jmetz I posted the function. I don't know how to slice the image from the peaks. My idea is to slice the image based on two consecutive peaks, but there are many peaks there, can you show me your trial please ?

Comment: Also missing is `normalize` - if you post a working code sample that I can modify I can post a complete working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To slice an image from coordinates in a list, which you have in `peaks`, you can use:

```
all_slices = []
for i in range(len(peaks)-1):
    x0, x1 = peaks[i:i+2]
    image_slice = img[:, x0:x1]
    # Now do something with the slice, e.g. 
    all_slices.append(image_slice)
```

For your specific case the complete listing is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal.signaltools as sigtool
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths, find_peaks_cwt


def image_reduce(img):
    col_counts = cv2.reduce(img, 0, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)
    column = col_counts.flatten().tolist()
    # print("Column counts:\n\n", column)
    return column


def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm == 0:
        return v
    return v / norm


def slice_digits(image_name):
    img = cv2.imread(image_name, 0)

    column_frequency = image_reduce(cv2.bitwise_not(img))
    column_frequency = normalize(column_frequency)

    env = np.abs(sigtool.hilbert(column_frequency))

    square_sig = (env > 0.1)
    square_sig = square_sig.astype(float)
    square_sig = np.divide(square_sig, 15.0)
    square_sig = np.where((column_frequency > 0), 0.1, 0)

    peaks, _ = find_peaks(env > 0.1)
    plt.plot(env)
    plt.scatter(peaks, env[peaks],  s=50, c='r')

    edges = np.nonzero(np.diff(square_sig))[0]
    plt.scatter(edges, env[edges], c='g')

    all_slices = []
    for i in range(len(peaks) - 1):
        x0, x1 = peaks[i:i + 2]
        image_slice = img[:, x0:x1]

        print("coords:", x0, x1)
        # Now do something with the slice, e.g.
        all_slices.append(image_slice)
        plt.figure("Slice %d)" % i)
        plt.imshow(image_slice)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = r"c:\ahmed\doc.png"
    res_image = slice_digits(image)
```

Comment: The problems there are many peaks, I want to get the max peaks between the two segments of letters, then plot it. It's kinda like a simple OCR

Comment: The code above will create slices corresponding to the pairs of red peaks you plotted.

Comment: did you test it ? image_slice is zero, can you please test it ?

Comment: I can't test it until you have updated your code snippet to be completely runnable (see the comment on your question) - all functions need to be defined!

Comment: here is a runnable code, please look at the edited post

Comment: Updated answer accordingly - I was simply slicing the wrong dimension. Works on my machine.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I have another question.. If you see the letters has some spacing, the letters that are sliced, actually it didn't segment well the letters.. do you have another approach or idea to fix it, so that I can segment the image well and better ?

Comment: If you notice, the peaks are actually wrong, did you notice that ?

Comment: Ask a new SO question :)

Comment: I'm banned to ask in next two days.. please answer it here

Comment: You can add arbitrary borders to the sliced images by modifying `x0` and `x1`; e.g. before performing the slicing update `x0 -= 20` and `x1 += 20`, for example (though you have to make sure that `x0 >=0` and `x1 < image width`

Comment: yes, but the peaks are wrong, if you look at the image of the peaks, they are not correct, do you know why ?

Comment: You technique for detecting letters is possibly not appropriate for this task. I'm afraid I can't really comment more at the moment. Good luck devising a better strategy!